# Send receive files with jquery and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Hi I am attempting to transfer files to and from a java based custom server. The server uses outputstream to send and receive files and it takes in a byte array. Is there similar method to split the file into a byte array with jquery and send over TCP socket in php script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Ajax File Upload plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/). It worked for me!

```
function ajaxFileUpload()
{
    //starting setting some animation when the ajax starts and completes
    $("#loading")
    .ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxComplete(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    /*
        prepareing ajax file upload
        url: the url of script file handling the uploaded files
                    fileElementId: the file type of input element id and it will be the index of  $_FILES Array()
        dataType: it support json, xml
        secureuri:use secure protocol
        success: call back function when the ajax complete
        error: callback function when the ajax failed

            */
    $.ajaxFileUpload
    (
        {
            url:'doajaxfileupload.php', 
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, status)
            {
                if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                {
                    if(data.error != '')
                    {
                        alert(data.error);
                    }else
                    {
                        alert(data.msg);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (data, status, e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    )

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!. But how can the php script take the file you send to it and convert it to byte array and send over TCP socket? Tcp socket only takes buffered string.

Comment: The file will be uploaded to the webserver by the AJAX call. In your PHP code you can retrive the file from the $_FILES array. $_FILES['fileToUpload'] to be more specific since the name of the html file input element was 'fileToUpload'.

Comment: Read more about the PHP $_FILES array and it's usage [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? This way the jquery script downloads the file onto the webserver and the php script reads it, converts it to a byte array and sends to our custom server?